# Support for TLS_1.1 in ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ruby-1.9.3

One of client has notified that they would be upgrading their SSL version to **TLS1.1** and would be cease the support of **TLS1.0**

Reading [these](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg75398.html), I came to know that OpenSSL handle the protocol negotiation automatically.

Now, given my current **RUBY version** i.e 1.9.3 and available Openssl Version **"OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014"** (complied against ruby)

I see this

> [:TLSv1, :TLSv1_server, :TLSv1_client, :SSLv3, :SSLv3_server,
>   :SSLv3_client, :SSLv23, :SSLv23_server, :SSLv23_client]

as the list of available SSL protocols supported by openssl.

So, do I have to upgrade?

- Openssl Version and not upgrade ruby version just recompile the current version it with new openssl **OR**
- Only Upgrade Ruby (since RVM would upgrade the openssl library for it) **OR**
- No Update is is need the Current Version of Ruby and Openssl can work with TLS1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable TLS v1.2 in Ruby? If so, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059059/is-it-possible-to-enable-tls-v1-2-in-ruby-if-so-how)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich to some extent, **YES** I did cross check the answer before posting here but I could not find any info that if TLSv1.1 is supported in ruby methods what should the approach i.e  Upgrade ?                                                                                   a) Openssl Version and not upgrade ruby version just recompile the current version it with new openssl **OR**
b) Only Upgrade Ruby (since RVM would upgrade the openssl library for it) **OR**
c) No Update is is need the Current Version of Ruby and Openssl can work with TLS1.1

Comment: Support must be both in OpenSSL and in Ruby. So you need to upgrade both.