# Use TLS1.1 or 1.2 In Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am trying to make an http call via rest api from my ruby code, but the server will only accept TLSv1.1 or newer. The default seems to be TLSv1.0.

I've found this forum which seems to solve my problem,

[Is it possible to enable TLS v1.2 in Ruby? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059059/is-it-possible-to-enable-tls-v1-2-in-ruby-if-so-how)

but when I try to Implement, I get

```
Error: #<ArgumentError: unknown SSL method `TLSv1_2'.>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Also see [How to set SSLContext options in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3818232/608639) and [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213). I've become so frustrated in doing simple Security 101 things in Ruby I no longer use it.