# How to update SSL certificate of Ruby for Paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi i want to implement paypal credit card option in my applictaion. i am using ruby-1.9.2-p290 and rails 3.0.3. paypal sdk is working fine with ruby 2.3.0 but i have to implement with ruby-1.9.2-p290 but getting an exception unknown SSL method `TLSv1_2'.
so can anyone can tell me how i can update ssl certificate of ruby-1.9.2-p290 so that i can remove this issue. Thanks in advance :)

following Ruby SDK for PayPal RESTful APIs :-
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

Comment: Why do you have to use Ruby 1.9.2? It reached its end of life more than 3 years ago. IMHO the requirement for such an old version is the issue you need to solve first.

Comment: i have to use Ruby 1.9.2. actually i am working on a live project so cant upgrade it right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059059/is-it-possible-to-enable-tls-v1-2-in-ruby-if-so-how

Comment: thanx for your response. do you have any idea where to add                     ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2                                                                                      as mention in the above link.

Comment: You can't, because  - as written in the answer and the comments to the answer - this fix wasn't backported to Ruby 1.9.2. Ruby 1.9.2 is unmaintained for many years already. Your version of Ruby is older than the first version of the gem you are trying to use. You cannot expect it to support libraries that were introduced after its end-of-life. Same for your Rails version that is more than 6 years old.

Comment: what about Ruby 1.9.3? can i implement the same with Ruby 1.9.3?